# Open issues on github with script

Tags: github

I want to create a feedback box for my website for beta testing. I don't even know if this is possible but is there a way to open issues on github with a script. I've never done anything like this before so I want to check if it's possible. Basically, when a user reports a bug I want to run a script to automatically open an issue.

I am running Linux btw.

Thanks

Comment: If you are searching for something ready-made, [Usersnap](https://usersnap.com/github) fits your needs. Add a small JavaScript library to your page and get a feedback box and the possibility to annotate the web page. You can even decide which issues will be sent to GitHub to filter out user comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Github has official developers API. [Here's the part about creating issues](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues#create-an-issue). As most others API, it will need you to get access token, to b able make calls to this API, so if you are not familiar with web api's, it's better to dive in this from the [first topic](http://developer.github.com/v3/) on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this here as a potential (easy) solution because you can write a script that can authenticate you in and create an issue in about 4 lines. I've been digging into this for a few days now and after trying many different methods, I think your best bet is the PHP API https://github.com/ornicar/php-github-api which is compatible with the github API v2 (but not with v3 yet).

This was an incredibly impressive lib considering that I tried doing similar work; first in jQuery (which is a terrible idea due to POSTing issues with the Cross Origin Resource Sharing policy) and then cURL (this was met with similar disaster). This lib is a godsend, you can use it with all the API's and for Basic authentication / access_tokens.

If you don't want to use PHP there are many different API's for v2 that you can use http://develop.github.com/p/libraries.html that support any coding solution you need. Hope this helps somebody down the line.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with the API as Igor suggests, but I'd like to point out that user feedback and issue tracking are two entirely different beasts and it's usually best to not treat them as the same thing.  You should probably send feedback to email or even something like tenderapp.com, and have a human behind that.  Said human can then triage those, sending out replies so users know they've been heard, and opening issues when necessary.

Comment: Yeah that's actually my intention. I'll intercept all the feedback messages and when I think something is worth investigating I'll open the issue. It wouldn't make any sense to open an issue directly after a user sent something. I'll check out tenderapp.com. Thanks a lot